# Mime type warnings for empty filename

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3

Is there a way to get rid of these warnings? What does it mean by `file ""`. I've already added below in web.xml

```
00000030 context       W   JSF1091: No mime type could be found for file "".  
To resolve this, add a mime-type mapping to the applications web.xml.
```

**web.xml**

```
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>gif</extension>
    <mime-type>image/gif</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>jpeg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>jpg</extension>
    <mime-type>image/jpeg</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>
    <extension>png</extension>
    <mime-type>image/png</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping> 
     <extension>xml</extension> 
     <mime-type>application/xml</mime-type> 
</mime-mapping>
```

Answer (score 1):

presumably its too late but I came across the same issue recently.

in your controller where you load the image you have to put a link to the filename of it.

i.e.

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{displayImage.file}" **name="#{image.filename}"** alt="Image Description for #{image.description}" stream="true" title="#{image.copyrightnote}">
```

hope it helps.
cheers gan